# Calling multiple methods from Worker-Thread in SwingWorker (doInBackground)?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, swingworker

I'm new to Thread and wanted to use the SwingWorker for updating my GUI, while another thread is analyzing some html and downloading files..

Here's my code:

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

    analyzeHTML();
    download();

    return null;
}
```

The whole call is failing sometimes:

```
   SEVERE: null
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:579)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1322)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:429)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:446)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:446)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
    at hanserdownloader.LinkProcessorThread.analyzeHTML(LinkProcessorThread.java:208)
    at hanserdownloader.LinkProcessorThread.doInBackground(LinkProcessorThread.java:139)
    at hanserdownloader.LinkProcessorThread.doInBackground(LinkProcessorThread.java:113)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**So my question is:**

Are these two methods above also running in the worker-thread, when they are called from one/doInBackground(). Should be, right?

Seems to be a dumb question, but I'm a bit unsettled, if this timeout-error isn't really produced by some thread mess (instead of a real http-timeout)..

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The two methods are running in a worker thread, but sequentially. So, `analyzeHTML` is called first, within a worker thread, then when it's done, `download` is called in that same thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It really was the fault of the server, which caused a timeout. I increased the max-Timeout in my jsoup-component. Today it works like a charm ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `doInBackground` is running in a separate thread from the Event Dispatching Thread.  Any methods you call will be called within this same thread context, unless you change it somehow.

So, if all things go well, first `analyzeHTML` will be called, when it has completed, `download` will be called.

It also depends though, in your example, if the first method throws an `Exception` of same kind, the second method will not be called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And the problem was really the fault of the server, which caused a timeout!